# Middleman blog - How to ensure that article.path translates to an absolute path?

Tags: ruby, blogs, middleman

I hope somebody can help -

In my Middleman project, I want the blog articles to be in a subdirectory inside `/source/` (so for instance '/source/webdev/blog/).
I've followed the instructions, and muddled through (I'm new to Middleman and a complete Ruby newbie) and got the links to appear when calling: `article.path`
HOWEVER - the links appear as relative urls, regardless of what I set in config.rb.

I've disabled  `:relative_assets` (didn't seem to make any difference anyway), and I'm not using 'directory_indexes'. Any help would be immense!

My config.rb looks like this:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  # set options on blog
  blog.permalink = "/webdev/blog/{year}/{title}.html"    # but article.path ends up relative!
  blog.sources = "/webdev/blog/{year}/{title}.html"   
end
```

So my blog articles get built to `/webdev/blog/2014/test-article.html`, which is what I want.

In a partial that I'm hoping to use anywhere on the site, not just the homepage:

```
<ul>
     <% blog.articles.each do |article| %>
       <li>
         <%= link_to article.title, article.path %>
       </li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

This gives me a list of links, as expected, but with relative URLs - which means, yep, when the links list is on a page in `/webdev/`, they take me to `/webdev/webdev/blog/2014/some-article.html` grrrr...

What could I be doing wrong? Is there some setting in options I've missed?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I'm not familiar with middleman, but don't you need a leading slash in `blog.sources`?

Comment: From what I've gleaned, in Middleman blog, 'blog.sources' is where it looks for the article files to build and that part is working for me with or without the leading slash. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll edit to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't quite the answer I was looking for, but I've managed to 'fix' the issue for now - not very elegantly, I'll admit (Did I mention I don't speak Ruby?).

After some desperate messing about, I physically added a forward slash to `article.path` like so:

```
= link_to article.title, '/'+ article.path
```

..and it worked.

I'm going with this for now.

I would still love to know if there is a real solution to this little problem out there...

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration needs to be added to your `config.rb`:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
 blog.prefix = "webdev/blog"
end
```

Your blog posts should then be generated in your desired location.

Comment: Thanks - that was my original config setting, but I removed/changed it to my current setting because I couldn't get `blog.articles.each` to pick up any links. As I was new to all this, I decided it would be simpler for me to decipher URL issues than why the iteration on blog.articles was coming up blank.