# Middleman blog - Where can I see a list of all options I can set in config.rb?

Tags: ruby, resources, blogs, middleman

I'm really new to ruby, as is probably evident from my question. But so far I've managed to get along ok with my Middleman project. That is, until I hit some trouble with the blog extension (a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461067/middleman-blog-how-to-ensure-that-article-path-translates-to-an-absolute-path)).

Despite reading the [documentation at Middlemanapp](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/)
I still haven't figured what options exist that I can set inside my config.rb file, when I activate blogging.

e.g.

```
activate :blog do |blog|
    blog.sources
    blog.permalink
    # what other options are at my disposal?
end
```

Where can I find the list of options, or do I need to get under the bonnet and look at the extension files at github or something? (Did I mention I don't speak Ruby?)

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `bundle exec middleman server` in your project dir and visit `http://localhost:4567/__middleman/config/` .

You will see a list of all options with explanations.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise all the extensions were listed there as well - Thank you thank you!